# Using Express' router.get with a cronjob

Tags: node.js, cron

I'm using [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) and Express.js

I want my cronjob to run every 5 seconds but I also must return a response, so I'm using router.get. However, it doesn't run. Using cron or not, how can I trigger `/getThings` every 5 seconds?

```
new cron('*/5 * * * * *', function () {
  router.get('/getThings', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });

}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle it in your Frontend. With Express you can send a response only once per request. So if you want a Status-Update after 4 sec, send a new request from your frontend every 4 seconds (while loop).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to define your express routes normally. Then inside your cron function you would make a request to that express route you have defined.

To make a request in your cron function, you can use node default http module, or for easier and cleaner way you can use modules like request or axios. You can find them all on npm.